# Do you use present continuous for something that you are not doing right now?

Tags: present-continuous

1-A) I study math at school.

1-B) I am studying math at school.

Can I use 1-B when I am not studying math at the moment I am speaking?  In my understanding, I use 1-B if the math course is temporary and I will stop studying it after finishing the course.  Is it correct?

2-A) I wake up at five these days.

2-B) I am waking up at five these days.

My understanding is that I use 2-B if the habit of waking up early lasts for a short period of time, because I have morning practice for the coming competition, for example, and that I will not wake up at five once the competition is over.

Is my understanding correct?

Answer (score 1):

You are correct in the permanent or temporary thing. There are many differences in the ***present simple*** and ***present continuous***, and whether it is temporary or permanent is one of them.

This is the one you're talking about in your example.

> I study math at school.

> I am studying math at school.

These two are different. We use the ***present simple*** to talk about **permanent** facts and general truths. On the contrary, we use the ***present continuous*** to talk about something **temporary**.

## Attributions

https://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/present-perfect-simple-or-present-perfect-continuous

Comment: **I study math at school** is "permanent" for as long as that person remains in school, likewise the P. Continuous form. We don't know if the class lasts one week or three years. Furthermore, to answer the OP, it is not necessary to be in a math class at the moment of speaking.

Comment: How do you use bold in comment?

Comment: Place two asterisks on either side of ** the word or phrase ** but with no spaces.